# Jmeter generate HTTP TimeStampRequest RFC3161

Tags: jmeter, rfc3161

I would like to use Jmeter to generate HTTP TimeStampRequests "application/timestamp-query" as presented in the standard RFC3161.
Currently I'm using Java program to do it but I would like to improve it by using Jmeter functionalities.

Is it possible to do it ?

Comment: you can run your code in JSR223 Sampler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers you can:

1. Compile your code into .jar file
2. Put the .jar into [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
3. Use the function from the .jar file to generate the request body from the [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor)
4. Set the request body to the value generated in the step 3

More information:

- [How to Reuse Your JMeter Code with JAR Files and Save Time](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-reuse-your-jmeter-code-with-jar-files-and-save-time)
- [Programmatically set POST binary content to HTTP sampler in Jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60126446/programmatically-set-post-binary-content-to-http-sampler-in-jmeter)

Comment: it works great ! btw how can I get back a status failed or success to a specific JSR223 test ? depending on JAR Method response I would like to highlight result tests.